# Appending clip path in d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to upgrade an old **v3** chart to **v4** and got stuck at trying to append `clipPath`.

At first I thought that the way to append clip path was changed in v4 somehow but It appears to be the same as before.

My reference is [Mike Bostocks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/978f6c03c9aab8af8594) chart.

And [**here's**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DyOPO10MSEhh1izSQ9Mc?p=preview) the progress I've made so far.

One thing i've tried was basically to copy/paste the `line` path logic and change:

`line(d.values)` to `area(d.values)`

I get no errors from this so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the  y scale was not being calculated within the same environment as the clip path - giving the clip path a height of 0. I moved the clip path to the update function.  You can probably get a more elegant update of the clip path, but I added a line at the top to remove the existing clip path so a new one could be appended: https://plnkr.co/edit/KQC1A70b4O5fNtHrQEkn?p=preview

```
    function update() {

      d3.selectAll('clipPath').remove();

      VALUE = d3.select('#selectbox').property('value');

      d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, _, columns) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) 
        d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
        return d;
      }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;
    baseValue = data[0]["Category" + VALUE];

    console.log(baseValue)

    var keys = data.columns.slice(1,2); 

    var copy = [];

    keys.forEach(function(t) {
      t = t.slice(0, -2) // Slice last two letters
      copy.push(t) // Push sliced strings into copy array
    });

    var cities = copy.map(function(id) {
      return {
        id: id,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {date: d.date, city: d[id+VALUE] / baseValue};
        })
      };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) { 
        return d3.min(c.values, function(d) { 
          return d.city;
        }); 
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) { 
        return d3.max(c.values, function(d) { 
          return d.city;
        }); 
      })
    ]);



    defs.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip-above")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", y(1));

        area.y0(y(1));

    yAxis.tickValues(d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(y.domain())
        .ticks(20));

    gY.transition().duration(durations).call(yAxis);

    gY.selectAll(".tick")
        .classed("tick--one", function(d) { return Math.abs(d - 1) < 1e-6; });

    g.selectAll(".axis.axis--x").transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .call(xAxis);

    // ========= Above Clip =========

    var above = g.selectAll(".above")
      .data(cities);

    above = above
      .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-above)")
      .attr("class", "area area--above above")
      .merge(above);

    above.transition()
      .duration(durations)
      .attr("d", function(d) {return area(d.values)} );

    // ========= Line Path =========

    var cityLine = g.selectAll(".cities")
      .data(cities);

    cityLine = cityLine
      .enter()
    .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line cities")
      .merge(cityLine);

    cityLine.transition()
      .duration(durations)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values) });

    afterLoad();

});
```